# Rredireccionameinto y Virtual hosts

Tags: servidor, dns, windows-server-2012, fedora

Tengo un dilema que no puedo resolver. Tengo un servidor Windows detrás de una IP publica que aloja una pagina web. También tengo un servidor fedora que aloja un sistema web. Utilice el Port Fowarding del router para que todos los paquetes que lleguen a la ip pública y al puerto 4443 se redirijan a la ip del server fedora al puerto 443 y así poder servir la pagina web del servidor windows y acceder de forma remota al sistema web en fedora (esto esta funcionando). El tema es que ahora quiero alojar otra pagina web en el server fedora y no se como realizar la configuracion DNS con cloudfare, ya puse la pagina en el server fedora, puedo acceder poniendo [www.midominio.com.ar](http://www.midominio.com.ar) pero el navegador del cliente me muestra en la barra de navegacion la 'ip-publica:4443/mipagina' y además me dice que el certificado no es válido. Osea me gustarpia que se pueda acceder a mi nueva página en mi server fedora ingresando en el navegador [www.mipagina.com.ar](http://www.mipagina.com.ar), que me detecte el certificado y que nome muestre la ip y el puerto en la barra de navegación. No se si me explique bien. GRACIAS de antemano.!!!